# Jetpack turning on when I finish climbing a ladder on my rover?

Tags: space-engineers

Every time I climb the boarding ladder from my rover, my jetpack turns on even though there's a perfectly good platform right there.

How do I prevent this so that folk can easily board my rover without having to jump, or build a bulky boarding ramp setup?

Answer (score 1):

If the platform is outside of an artificial gravity field, the jetpack will turn itself on if you detach from a position where you can move without the use of it. For example, dismounting a ladder, jumping off a surface you are mag-locked to with the magnetic boots. To prevent this, you should have an artificial gravity field encompassing the area where the player dismounts the ladder so that the game does not think you are free floating in space.

If the platform is already within an artificial gravity field, ensure it is the correct size and orientation, you can do so by showing the gravity field by going to the grid's gravity generator and selecting "Show gravity field" under the generator's properties, and then in the info tab choosing "Show on HUD."

If the artificial gravity field is already correctly configured, consider opening a [bug report](https://support.keenswh.com/spaceengineers/pc) on the Keen Software House forums.